# Overwrite the elements in a vector without specifying specific elements

Tags: c++, vector, io, stdvector, std-pair

I am making a calculator that accepts multiple operators at once. I have a vector pair that stores the position of operators, and the type of operator. The vector must be updated after each loop as the previous positions are no longer valid due to the result replacing a part of the input string.

I've attempted to use `clear()` so that it starts from the beginning again, but that results in `Expression: vector iterators incompatible`. I don't think I can use `std::replace` since the number of operators in the string changes after each loop. Is there a way to just have it start from the beginning again and overwrite any existing elements?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "C++ Calculator" << std::endl;

    while (true) //runs forever with loop
    {
        std::string input;
        std::getline(std::cin, input);

        //erases whitespace
        int inp_length = input.length();
        for (int i = inp_length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            if (input[i] == ' ')
                input.erase(i, 1);
        }
        
        std::vector<std::pair<int, char>> oper_pvec;
        int vec_pos = 0;

        //finds the position of operators and type
        for (std::string::iterator i = input.begin(); i != input.end(); ++vec_pos, ++i)
        {
            switch (*i)
            {
                case 'x':
                {
                    oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vec_pos, 'x'));
                    break;
                }
                case '/':
                {
                    oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vec_pos, '/'));
                    break;
                }
                case '+':
                {
                    oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vec_pos, '+'));
                    break;
                }
                case '-':
                {
                    oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vec_pos, '-'));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //declarations before loop to make sure they're all able to be accessed, will probably change later
        int loper_pos = 0; //must be set 0 since there's no left operator at first
        int roper_pos;
        double lnum; //left number
        double rnum; //right number
        char loper; //left operator
        char roper; //right operator
        int pos = -1; //position of loop, needs to be -1 since it increments it each time
        std::string holder = input; //copy of input

        auto op = oper_pvec.begin();
        while (op != oper_pvec.end())
        {
            op = oper_pvec.begin();
            ++pos; //position of loop
            int key = std::get<0>(*op); //gets first value from vector pair
            char val = std::get<1>(*op); //gets second value from vector pair


            //gets previous/next vector pairs
            std::vector<std::pair<int, char>>::iterator prev_op = oper_pvec.begin();
            std::vector<std::pair<int, char>>::iterator next_op = oper_pvec.end();

            if (op != oper_pvec.begin()) prev_op = std::prev(op);
            if (op != oper_pvec.end()) next_op = std::next(op);


            //extracts the value of pairs
            if (pos > 0)
            {
                loper_pos = std::get<0>(*prev_op);
                loper = std::get<1>(*prev_op);
            }
            if (pos == oper_pvec.size() - 1) roper_pos = oper_pvec.size();
            else
            {
                roper_pos = std::get<0>(*next_op);
                roper = std::get<1>(*next_op);
            }


            //replaces numbers and etc with product, only multiplication for now
            switch (val)
            {
                case 'x':
                {
                    int lnum_start = loper_pos + 1;
                    if (loper_pos == 0) lnum_start = 0;

                    int lnum_len = key - (loper_pos + 1);
                    if (loper_pos == 0) lnum_len = key;

                    lnum = std::stod(input.substr(lnum_start, lnum_len));

                    int rnum_start = key + 1;
                    int rnum_len = (roper_pos - 1) - key;
                    rnum = std::stod(input.substr(rnum_start, rnum_len));

                    double prod = lnum * rnum;
                    std::string to_string = std::to_string(prod);
                    input.replace(loper_pos, roper_pos, to_string);
                    break;
                }
            }

            /////////////////////////////////problem area////////////////////////////////////////

            //clears the vector and then finds the operators again
            oper_pvec.clear();
            int vpos = 0;
            for (std::string::iterator it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); ++vpos, ++it)
            {
                if (vpos == input.length())
                {
                    vpos = 0;
                    break;
                }
                switch (*it)
                {
                    case 'x':
                    {
                        oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vpos, 'x'));
                        break;
                    }
                    case '/':
                    {
                        oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vpos, '/'));
                        break;
                    }
                    case '+':
                    {
                        oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vpos, '+'));
                        break;
                    }
                    case '-':
                    {
                        oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vpos, '-'));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
        //converts to double then prints on screen
        double out = std::stod(input);
        std::cout << out << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) – define your expectations, the code you're trying to modify but failing, etc.

Comment: Unrelated, but you can use `oper_pvec.push_back({vec_pos, '/'})` to make the code compact.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but since `input` is read with `std::cin >> input` there won't be any spaces in it. The stream extractor stops when it encounters whitespace. So there's no need for that loop to remove spaces.

Comment: Instead of storing string position, you might got two vectors, one for operands, one for operators. (especially as you don't handle parenthesis; with parenthesis, build a tree).

Comment: Can you mention an example input, the output/error you are getting and desired output.

Comment: @PeteBecker I needed that because originally it only needed 1 operator and so it used the positions behind and in front of the operator. Probably unnecessary now since I removed that part.-

Comment: @Shidouuu -- my comment has nothing to do with what the code does with the input. It's simply about how the code **reads** the input text. There won't be any spaces in the input.

Comment: @Jarod42 That might be a good idea.


@risingStark An example input would be `5x5x5`, sometimes I would receive an incorrect output like `25` or `525`, currently I'm getting `Expression: vector iterators incompatible`

Comment: @PeteBecker Huh, seems like you're right, it does stop at the whitespace. Looks like my old code doesn't actually work with spaces and I just kinda forgot about it not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really the answer to the title but instead of trying to overwrite the vector I just continued to use `clear()` and changed the while loop to `oper_pvec.size() != 0`.

(Full code since I had to change quite a few things to get it to work properly)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "C++ Calculator" << std::endl;

    while (true) //runs forever with loop
    {
        std::string input;
        std::getline(std::cin, input);

        //erases whitespace
        int inp_length = input.length();
        for (int i = inp_length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            if (input[i] == ' ')
                input.erase(i, 1);
        }
        
        std::vector<std::pair<int, char>> oper_pvec;
        int vec_pos = 0;

        //finds the position of operators and type
        for (std::string::iterator i = input.begin(); i != input.end(); ++vec_pos, ++i)
        {
            switch (*i)
            {
                case 'x':
                {
                    oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vec_pos, 'x'));
                    break;
                }
                case '/':
                {
                    oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vec_pos, '/'));
                    break;
                }
                case '+':
                {
                    oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vec_pos, '+'));
                    break;
                }
                case '-':
                {
                    oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vec_pos, '-'));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //declarations before loop to make sure they're all able to be accessed, will probably change later
        int loper_pos = 0; //must be set 0 since there's no left operator at first
        int roper_pos;
        double lnum; //left number
        double rnum; //right number
        char loper; //left operator
        char roper; //right operator
        int pos = -1; //position of loop, needs to be -1 since it increments it each time
        std::string holder = input; //copy of input

        std::vector<std::pair<int, char>> vec_copy = oper_pvec;

        auto op = oper_pvec.begin();
        while (oper_pvec.size() != 0)
        {
            op = oper_pvec.begin();
            ++pos; //position of loop
            int key = std::get<0>(*op); //gets first value from vector pair
            char val = std::get<1>(*op); //gets second value from vector pair


            //gets previous/next vector pairs
            std::vector<std::pair<int, char>>::iterator prev_op = oper_pvec.begin();
            std::vector<std::pair<int, char>>::iterator next_op = oper_pvec.end();

            if (op != oper_pvec.begin()) prev_op = std::prev(op);
            if (op != oper_pvec.end()) next_op = std::next(op);


            //extracts the value of pairs
            if (pos > 0)
            {
                loper_pos = std::get<0>(*prev_op);
                loper = std::get<1>(*prev_op);
            }
            if (op == oper_pvec.begin()) loper_pos = 0;

            if (oper_pvec.size() == 1) roper_pos = input.length();          
            else
            {
                roper_pos = std::get<0>(*next_op);
                roper = std::get<1>(*next_op);
            }


            //replaces numbers and etc with product, only multiplication for now
            switch (val)
            {
                case 'x':
                {
                    int lnum_start = loper_pos + 1;
                    if (lnum_start == 1) lnum_start = 0;

                    if (loper_pos > 0)
                        if (isdigit(input[loper_pos - 1])) lnum_start = 0;

                    int lnum_len = key - (loper_pos + 1);
                    if (lnum_start == 0)
                    {
                        if (key == 1) lnum_len = 1;
                        else lnum_len = key - 1;
                    }
                    lnum = std::stod(input.substr(lnum_start, lnum_len));

                    int rnum_start = key + 1;
                    int rnum_len = (roper_pos - 1) - key;
                    rnum = std::stod(input.substr(rnum_start, rnum_len));

                    double prod = lnum * rnum;
                    std::string to_string = std::to_string(prod);
                    input.replace(loper_pos, roper_pos, to_string);
                    break;
                }
            }

            //clears the vector and then finds the operators again
            oper_pvec.clear();
            int vpos = 0;
            for (std::string::iterator it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); ++vpos, ++it)
            {
                if (vpos == input.length())
                {
                    vpos = 0;
                    break;
                }
                switch (*it)
                {
                    case 'x':
                    {
                        oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vpos, 'x'));
                        break;
                    }
                    case '/':
                    {
                        oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vpos, '/'));
                        break;
                    }
                    case '+':
                    {
                        oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vpos, '+'));
                        break;
                    }
                    case '-':
                    {
                        oper_pvec.push_back(std::pair<int, char>(vpos, '-'));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //converts to double then prints on screen
        double out = std::stod(input);
        std::cout << out << std::endl;
    }
}
```